# Compiles on Xcode, doesn't compile on visual studio

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I recently submitted an assignment via email to a professor.  He says that my code doesn't compile.  From what I understand, he's using Visual Studio while I'm using XCode on a mac.  From my computer the code compiles fine and does everything its asked to do.  Its a real number finder, so you can type in a non-real number and its rejected, and you can type in a real number and it will thank you for it.

Can anyone tell me what I might be able to change about it so that it compiles for my professor?

Thanks

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cctype>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
double getaReal();  //function prototype
double realnumber;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
realnumber = getaReal();
cout << "The number entered is a real number: " <<realnumber << endl;

return 0;
 }

 bool isvalidReal(string str)         //function to find real numbers.
 {
int start = 0;
int i;
bool valid = true;
bool sign = false;

if (int(str.length()) == 0) valid = false;          //check for empty string
if (str.at(0) == '-' || str.at(0) == '+')            //check for sign
{
    sign = true;
    start = 1;                                   //check for real num at 
 position 1
}
if (sign && int(str.length()) == 1) valid = false;  //make sure there's 
 atleast 1 char after the sign

i = start;
while (valid && i<int(str.length()))
{
    if (!isdigit(str.at(i)) && (str.at(i) != '.'))  valid = false;  //found a non-digit character
    i++;                                  // move to next character
 }
 return valid;
 }

 double getaReal()
 {
bool isvalidReal(string);  //function declaration prototype
bool isnotreal = true;
string input;

while (isnotreal)
{
    try
    {
        cin >> input;     //accepts user input
        if (!isvalidReal(input)) throw input;
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << "No real number has been detected, continue to\n enter string values: ";
        continue;          //continues user input
    }
    isnotreal = false;
}
return atof(input.c_str());
 }
```

Comment: What error does your professor get?

Comment: @rsjaffe he's not a very helpful man.  its an online class and he's not very interactive.  I explained that it compiled and ran for me on my mac but he simply replied "well it doesn't work for me so sorry".

Comment: I think it may have to do with the way I declared the functions?